# Android progress dialog orentation change

Tags: android

Hello i have such problem, i have an asynctask and progress dialog and when i rotate my phone it fails, i know about that activity destoyed and we need to create new.
 So code.

```
public class GetWeather extends AsyncTask<String, Void, WeatherInfo> {
    FragmentActivity activity;
    public GetWeather(FragmentActivity a){
        activity = a;
    }
    static ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public void showDialog() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        /*Some stuff for dialog*/
        progressDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        showDialog();
    }
 protected void onPostExecute(WeatherInfo result){
        progressDialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

and my activity class

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements CityList.OnItemSelectedListener {
    GetWeather weather = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        weather = (GetWeather) getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance();
        if (weather != null){
            weather.activity = this;
            weather.showDialog();
        }
```

and it fails on dissmiss. How it is possible to fix? Thank you.

Comment: why your progress dialog is static?

Comment: @blackbelt i delete static - same